# The quotient of two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I have trouble solving the following problem:

---

The positive series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=1$. Prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ converges ($\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ isn't necessarily a positive series), and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k}{\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k}=1$$

---

I tried to use the Stolz-Cesaro theorem, and also tried if  it's available to solve this problem like [limit of quotient of two series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100338/limit-of-quotient-of-two-series), but I couldn't make it. Any help would be apprecicated, thanks!

Comment: What part do you have trouble with? What techniques are you allowed to use, are we talking about epsilons and deltas here or a more handwavy calculus-style proof using some theorem?

Comment: I think epsilon-N will be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part the proof reduces to limit comparison test which is discussed for example here

- [Limit comparison test proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269837)

For the second part by Stolz-Cesaro we have

$$\frac{\sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k}{\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k}=\frac{L_b-B_n}{L_a-A_n}=\frac{\frac{L_b-B_n}n}{\frac{L_a-A_n}n}\sim \frac{-nb_n}{-na_n}\to 1$$

using that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{L_a-A_n}n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{L_a-A_{n+1}-L_a+A_n}{n+1-n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} -a_n \implies L_a-A_n \sim -na_n$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{L_b-B_n}n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{L_b-B_{n+1}-L_b+B_n}{n+1-n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} -b_n\implies L_b-B_n \sim -nb_n$$